# OpenProcess error 87 invalid parameter

Tags: winapi, makefile, getlasterror, openprocess

I'm trying to write a program which executes make.exe from MinGW distribution in the current directory and makes use of its STDOUT data and exit code. I have a handle to process STDOUT where I fetch data from, created with CreatePipe. When I get an ERROR_HANDLE_EOF on that pipe I assume the process has exited and try to get its exit code:

```
if(session->pid == 0) return;
HANDLE hp = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
            PROCESS_TERMINATE, TRUE, session->pid);
if(hp == NULL) {
    printf("OpenProcess(%i) failed, error: %i\n",
        session->pid, (int)GetLastError());
    return;
}
```

My code works on all other MinGW utilities I tested (like pwd, ls, etc.), I get the STDOUT and the exit code with no problem. But when I try it on make, the above code displays the following message:

"OpenProcess(2032) failed, error: 87"

I googled for error code 87, and it says "Invalid parameter". I don't see what could be invalid about a positive process id like 2032. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the handle from `CreateProcess` instead of using `OpenProcess` on the PID.

`OpenProcess` only works if the process object still exists.  By the time you call `OpenProcess` if the process object is gone - the result is a call with invalid parameter.

The success you got with other utilities is either due to a race condition (which may fail some times) or you kept the original handle to the child process open.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving a tip for someone else's purpose. I *managed* to reach the `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER (87)` by trying to open:

- a System process (0)
- an ID which belonged to a thread, not the process (reference to [YatoDev's post](https://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/2214463-post2.html)).

The second case may be a problem when you e.g. claim a result from [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid) directly, which is an *`identifier of the thread that created the window`*, instead of its pointer parameter (which gives you requested PID).

Answer (score 0):

Although the post is old: I noticed that I got `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` when the process existed, but owned by different user and/or Windows desktop and/or terminal server session.

Strange enough, the `WTSEnumerateProcess()` function does not suffer from this error, but is much more expensive, especially on a system that is already under heavy load with many processes (and a call my even exhaust windows kernel resources).

So, it is not possible to make a 'real' invalid parameter provided and access errors. I would have expected `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` instead (but a task manager invoked as regular/non-elevated user still shows all processes).

Look like some inconsistencies in Windows?