# WinApi OpenProcess error 87

Tags: c++, winapi

Im trying to open process using Wisual Studio 2012, c++ console application and get 87 error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#define EXTERN_DLL_EXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

EXTERN_DLL_EXPORT int setLastObject(LPCWSTR wname) {
    LPCWSTR str = _TEXT("Name of window");
    HWND wnd = FindWindow(NULL,wname);

    LPDWORD cpid = 0;
    DWORD pid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(wnd,cpid);

    HANDLE proc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,false,pid);
    int err = GetLastError();
    return err;
}
```

P.S. i get the pid correctly

Comment: I assume the error is located on `HANDLE proc = ...` is this correct? The following question's answer might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988082/openprocess-error-87-invalid-parameter If I were to hazard an educated guess the reason for this error is because of the `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` based on the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684880(v=vs.85).aspx What operating system was your applicatin compiled on and what operating system is it running on?

Comment: Do you actually check the handle you get back before checking for an error?  If you got a valid handle then the value from `GetLastError` is meaningless.

Comment: @user2387336 - Furthermore `OpenProcess` returns this error when the pid is invalid, so that could also be the problem, despite you thinking you got the pid correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns the id of the *thread* that created the window.

You need to use the corresponding process id, which is returned in the second argument. So something like this

```
EXTERN_DLL_EXPORT int setLastObject(LPCWSTR wname) {
    LPCWSTR str = _TEXT("Name of window");
    HWND wnd = FindWindow(NULL,wname);

    DWORD dwProcessId = 0;
    DWORD dwThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(wnd, &dwProcessId);

    HANDLE proc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,false,dwProcessId);
    int err = GetLastError();
    return err;
}
```

Also, you should really be checking that `FindWindow` has succeeded and if you *do* get a valid `HANDLE` you must remember to `CloseHandle` when you've finished with it.